# how to make a layer mask and save it as black and white jpeg

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

i want to make a layer mask in photoshop. after that i want to save the layer mask as a black and white JPEG. i want to use this black and white JPEG as a mask in photoscan. how do i do that?

Comment: Maybe you dont actually want to save masks as JPG. Anyway look into the channels panel.

Comment: Hey SeaChild, just wanted to welcome you to GD.SE!  If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have made your layer mask, CTRL/CMD + Left Click the layer mask to create a selection of the layer mask. Fill the selection with black (See Layer 2).

[image: Mask Selection]

Then hide all layers with the graphic and then save as a jpeg (In my example hide Layer 1).

If-need-be you can reverse the selection by Select -> Inverse.

Comment: @seachild if mine or any answer here answers your question, please remember to mark an answer as correct.

Comment: answer marked as correct. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps:

1. Make your mask the way you want
2. Select Channels tab, you will see your mask at the bottom
3. Target the mask channel, press Ctl-A to select all, then Ctrl-C to copy to the clipboard
4. Press Ctrl-N to create a new document which should automatically be in the size of the mask, create the new document
5. Press Ctrl-V to paste it into the new document

Now you can save it any way you like. Here are some screen captures for clues.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]